# Auto-Enrollment with manager approval, but auto-approval for re-enrollment

Tags: ad-certificate-services, pki

I have a certificate template (auto-enrolled) that must require manager approval.

To achieve this, I checked the **CA certificate manager approval** checkbox in the **Issuance Requirements** tab.

[image]
[image]

The computer does auto-enroll and the certificate is placed on the **Pending** queue on the CA.

My wish is that once the pending certificate was manually approved, certificates should be renewed, or updated if the template major version increments, without manager approval. But I can't get this to work.

When I increment the major version of the certificate, the request is never automatically issued, but again put into the **Pending** queue for manual issuance.

I tried changing the **Same criteria as for enrollment** to **Valid existing certificate** but this didn't change anything.

To speed up my troubleshooting, I used `certutil -pulse` to start the auto-enrollment process on the requesting computer.

Edit:

The auto-enrollment policy on the affected server:

[image]

Comment: What's on the __Subject__ tab?

Comment: @garethTheRed I added the subject tab.

Comment: And the PKI group policy?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in ADCS, or incorrect MSFT documentation. At this point, you cannot accomplish what you are trying to do. I'm reaching Microsoft on this regard to get explanations.

Comment: @garethTheRed I added the auto-enrollment policy. I assume that is what you meant by PKI group policy?

Comment: To be honest, they look identical to the setting I've used in the past.  However, I've not tried to increment the major version of the template and tested.  Going by what you've seen and what @Crypt32 said, it's unlikely I'd succeed!

Comment: One thought - you've not set the validity period to anything ridiculously short for the purpose of expediting testing have you?  Auto (re)enrollment fails when you issue certs for less than 8 hours or so - I usually set it to 24h even for testing.

Comment: I set it to one hour. I will set it to 24h and wait a day.

Comment: Today I check the CA and the certificate renewals are still set to pending state.

Comment: @Daniel as I said, either it is a doc bug, or ADCS CA bug. It is not your fault (not misconfiguration). Docs say that `existing valid certificate` overrides the CA manager approval checkbox. I was able to repro and the behavior contradicts with docs and I've opened a support case with MSFT.

Comment: Just updating the post. Appreciate your effort. Please let me know of the outcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've opened a support case with Microsoft on behalf of OP (TrackingID#2201120040008993) about the issue. As I pointed in comments, the OP's setup is correct and I was able to repro in my environment. The support ticket is opened against [MS-WCCE] protocol, [§3.2.1.4.2.1.4.2.2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wcce/d83e53a4-45f3-4348-91b0-23de0b764da4) specification.

Microsoft Support was able to confirm the issue. Further investigation discovered that Microsoft CA implements [MS-WCCE] [§3.2.2.6.2.1.4.5.7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wcce/9cc7ba15-fcbc-48b3-8a3b-121faef3d5ef) requirement to ignore `CT_FLAG_PEND_ALL_REQUESTS` flag when `CT_FLAG_PREVIOUS_APPROVAL_VALIDATE_REENROLLMENT` properly. However, further investigation found that Microsoft CA in one of internal request processing routines fails with `Bad Renewal Name` which attempts to bind requester UPN name to the one stored in Active Directory. However since it is computer template, the UPN is not available (hence the error) and renewal procedures are aborted and initial request procedures executed: request placed in pending requests. And this UPN binding condition is not documented anywhere.

I've set up same scenario for user template (which writes down the UPN in certificate) and it worked well: initial request was placed in pending requests, renewal automatically renewed and issued the certificate.

In current state, "valid existing certificate" option works for user templates only and doesn't work for computer templates. There is no available workaround.

I'm continuing conversations with Microsoft Support and will update this response when new information is available.

HTH

**Update 19.10.2022**

Microsoft published updated documentation which includes conditions the request must meet in order to enable "Valid existing certificate" enforcement: [[MS-WCCE] §3.2.2.6.2.1.4.8 CT_FLAG_PREVIOUS_APPROVAL_VALIDATE_REENROLLMENT Enforcement Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wcce/7ce28195-4499-4f14-be8f-956188409534)

Comment: I Just want to state that if the subject name is supplied in the request - Valid existing certificate works for computer templates.

Answer (score 0):

@crypt32, based on the MS-WCCE documentation you provided it seems like reenrollment without requiring approval will only work for user-based certificates, not computer . Is this a correct interpretation of what you shared?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/539632)